# How to get array data back to mobile screen from firebase (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to get back array data to the mobile screen.
The String in the firebase is retrieved easily but I have problem with array data.

1) main.dart :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'firestoreservice.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'taskscreen.dart';
import 'task.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter ToDo APP',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff543B7A),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Task> items;
  FirestoreService fireServ = new FirestoreService();
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> todoTasks;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    items=new List();

    todoTasks?.cancel();
    todoTasks=fireServ.getTaskList().listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
      final List<Task> tasks=snapshot.documents
          .map((documentSnapshot) => Task. fromMap(documentSnapshot.data))
          .toList();

      setState(() {
        this.items = tasks;
      });

    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _myAppBar(context),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 80,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    // The containers in the background
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: 80.0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                            child: Material(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              elevation: 14.0,
                              shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        '${items[index].name}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 20.0),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '${items[index].size}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 20.0),
                                      ),
                                         Container(
                                          child: Image.network(
                                        '${items[index].imageU}',
                                      )),


                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ]);
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }


  Widget todoType(String icontype) {
    IconData iconval;
    Color colorval;
    switch (icontype) {
      case 'travel':
        iconval = FontAwesomeIcons.mapMarkerAlt;
        colorval = Color(0xff4158ba);
        break;
      case 'shopping':
        iconval = FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingCart;
        colorval = Color(0xfffb537f);
        break;
      case 'gym':
        iconval = FontAwesomeIcons.dumbbell;
        colorval = Color(0xff4caf50);
        break;
      case 'party':
        iconval = FontAwesomeIcons.glassCheers;
        colorval = Color(0xff9962d0);
        break;
      default:
        iconval = FontAwesomeIcons.tasks;
        colorval = Color(0xff0dc8f5);
    //
    }
    return CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: colorval,
      child: Icon(iconval, color: Colors.white, size: 20.0),
    );
  }

  Widget _myAppBar(context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              const Color(0xFFFA7397),
              const Color(0xFFFDDE42),
            ],
            begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[

                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'ToDo Tasks',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.search,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          //
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

2) task.dart

```
class Task{
  String _name;
  String _size;

  Task(this._name  ,this._size);

  Task.map(dynamic obj){
    this._name = obj['name'];
    this._size=obj['size'];
  List<String> imageU= new List<String>();

  }

  String get  name=> _name;
  String get size=>_size;

  Task.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map){
    this._name = map['name'];
    this._size= map['size'];
     this.imageU= List.from(map['images']);
  }
}
```

---

3) firestoreservice.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'task.dart';

final CollectionReference myCollection =
Firestore.instance.collection('products');

class FirestoreService {
  Future<Task> createTODOTask(String name, String size) async {
    final TransactionHandler createTransaction = (Transaction tx) async {
      final DocumentSnapshot ds = await tx.get(myCollection.document());
};

    return Firestore.instance.runTransaction(createTransaction).then((mapData) {
      return Task.fromMap(mapData);
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('error: $error');
      return null;
    });
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getTaskList({int offset, int limit}) {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = myCollection.snapshots();

    if (offset != null) {
      snapshots = snapshots.skip(offset);
    }
    if (limit != null) {
      snapshots = snapshots.take(limit);
    }
    return snapshots;
  }
}
```

---

How to get back array data to the mobile screen. The String in the firebase is retrieved easily but I have a problem with array data.

[image: Firebase image]

Comment: It is not clear from your post: which is the array/list field here. Is it `images`? If yes, first add it to `Task` then you can extract like: `(map['images'] as List).map((e) => e.toString()).toList()` in `Task.fromMap`

Comment: it is images and size .See in image

Comment: I don't see it. which file?

Comment: And what should i use to display in main.dart, and image is under "Firebase image" title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert task.dart to see what solution will work:

```
class Task{

  String name;
 List<String> size= new List<String>();



   Task.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map){
    this.name = map['name'];

     this.size= List.from(map['size' ]);



  }

}
```

And make sure all the documents in the image have "size" field.